# .htaccess rewriterule accurate

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html /index.php?sezione=$1
```

It should work right. but there is a problem in this rewriterule: in fact it rewrite right:

```
www.example.com/index.php?sezione=hello to www.example.com/hello.html
```

But it rewrite also, and it shouldn't with

```
www.example.com/hello.htmlll  www.example.com/hello.htmlfed
```

And any other string after the html extension. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html$ /index.php?sezione=$1
```

Comment: I have another question:

    RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)\.html$ /articles/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
This rewrite:

    /articles/arttitle
and

    /articles/arttitle/
how to avoid this second rewrite? thank you!!

Comment: If there is no html at the end, there will be no rewrite. Therefor I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean there is a duplicate page: /articles/arttitle (that is a page) and /articles/arttitle/ that is a directory, also if i can get it only manually.

Comment: This should not work anyway. $ touch 123 // $ mkdir 123 // => Error message that says, that the folder 123 could not be written because there is already a file.